# single user vs multi user mode (without networking) init level 1 vs 2

Tags: linux, centos

I tried init 1 (single user mode) and i am still able to switch between users. So this leads me to think that maybe other users is not able to login if i have a network (hence single user mode)

Then i look at init 2 (multi user mode without networking).  So how does multi user work here compared to single user ?

Lastly is Microsoft Window (.e.g. 8) consider to be a multi-user OS ?

Regards,
Noob

Comment: This is a remnant of bygone days, when people could use ["dumb terminals"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal) to login to a computer, even when the network services were down.  I'm not sure there's much difference between levels 1 and 2 now.  … … …  Then again, do things like `cron` and `at` work in level 1?

Comment: One question per question is the correct form.  If you want to know a completely different thing about a completely different operating system, ask it in its own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using, per the tags on your question, Red Hat Enterprise Linux or CentOS. Since version 7, those have used systemd. As such:

**Forget about runlevels**; they exist, but only as compatibility shims. The systemd documentation states that the concept is "obsolete". If you're starting to learn this stuff on a systemd operating system, don't start there.

Learn about targets, not run levels.  Learn about `rescue.target`, `emergency.target`, `multi-user.target`, and `graphical.target`.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`bootup`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132